# Find row number of cells containing two alternating texts

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search column G for these two alternating texts and output their row numbers throughout column B, starting at B2.

The data looks something like:

```
Row    
 1    Charge
 2     7
 3     7
 4    Discharge
 5     2
 6    Charge
 7     9
```

It currently only finds the first "Charge", and the output would be as "$G$1" but it will not continue to find every other value. I would also like for the output to just be "1" instead of "$G$1"

```
Sub RowFinder()

    Dim Found As Range
    Dim SearchVal(1 To 2) As String

    SearchVal(1) = "Charge"
    SearchVal(2) = "Discharge"

    Set Found = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("General 
    Text").Columns("G").Find(what:=SearchVal(), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = Found.Row
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `= Found.Row` ?

Comment: D'oh - thanks! Now the only problem is that it doesn't loop between Charge and Discharge to find all instances in the column

Comment: Please don't edit your code to incorporate changes, it means that people won't be able to replicate your problem in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to have in `B2` the two lines separated by a comma, this should do:

```
Sub RowFinder()
    Range("B2").value = Join(Application.Match _
        (Array("Charge", "Discharge"), Sheets("General Text").Columns("G"), 0), ",")
End Sub
```

Output in "B2": `1,4`

Or if you want them in `B2` and `C2`:

```
Range("B2:c2").value = Application.Match _
        (Array("Charge", "Discharge"), Sheets("General Text").Columns("G"), 0)
```

And to have them in `B2` and `B3`:

```
Range("B2:B3").value = Application.Transpose(Application.Match _
    (Array("Charge", "Discharge"), Sheets("General Text").Columns("G"), 0))
```

Finally, you want to find them all, but in succession:

```
Sub RowFinder()
    Dim rng As Range, j As Long, lastCell As Range, ar
    ar = Array("Charge", "Discharge")
    j = 2
    With Sheets("General Text")
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)
        Set rng = .Range("G1", lastCell)
        On Error GoTo Finished
        Do
            .Cells(j, "B").value = rng.row - 1 + Application.Match(ar(j Mod 2), rng, 0)
            Set rng = .Range("G" & .Cells(j, "B").value, lastCell)
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    End With
Finished:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I mean that it will list it downwards so B2 has "1" and B3 has "4" etc.

Comment: B2 and B3 ok, easy change, but my problem is with the "etc". That's the unclear point in your question

Comment: Essentially, I want it to keep filling down column B with all the row numbers of any cells with "Charge" and "Discharge" found. Apologies for confusion

Comment: @MolarBear try the added last part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

another possibility, using `Autofilter()`, thus avoiding loops:

```
Sub RowFinder()
    Dim founds As Range
    With Worksheets("General Text") '<--| reference your worksheet
        With .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column G cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Charge", "Discharge"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter cells with "Charge" and "Discharge"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set founds = .Resize(.Rows.count - IIf(InStr("ChargeDischarge", .Cells(1)) > 0, 0, 1)).Offset(IIf(InStr("ChargeDischarge", .Cells(1)) > 0, 0, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If Not founds Is Nothing Then .Range("B2").Resize(founds.count) = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace(founds.Address(False, False), "G", ""), ","))
    End With
End Sub
```

where, if column G has a "header" in row 1, you can change:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set founds = .Resize(.Rows.count - IIf(InStr("ChargeDischarge", .Cells(1)) > 0, 0, 1)).Offset(IIf(InStr("ChargeDischarge", .Cells(1)) > 0, 0, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

to:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set founds = .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```